# Any issues with LAMP stack for web app? (security, scalability, speed, functionality, etc.)

Tags: php, security, scalability, lamp, enterprise

I'm building a simple communications platform for clients to submit applications to banks.  Basically a form of data will be submitted by one side and banks will be notified and can login to see applications submitted.

What I want to get people's opinions on is whether there are significant downsides to building this on a LAMP stack.  There should never be a ton of concurrent traffic, so I'm less concerned with scalability. The only thing I can think of that might be worthy of consideration, is security or performance, which I'm not too knowledgable about.

LAMP is what I know from building web apps in the past, and I'd like to use it for this project as well unless there's significant reason not to.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing insecure or "unperformant" with the LAMP stack. The greatest risk to security is in the system admins or web/db developers, who are not well educated in security issues, producing insecure code or configurations.

If you are not "too knowledgable" about security, and you are dealing with sensitive information, i highly recommend you hire someone who is, to help develop or test your application and server configs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used LAMP in several Alexa-top-200 companies with great results. It scales well and predictably, it's secure if administered properly, and extremely rapid with respect to development time involved. The only advantage I'd give Java in this case is the vast amount of "enterprise" library code.